# Windows Application .exe not updating by modifying Main method

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

I have created windows application to  .. I need to add arguments to Main method so I changed my main method by overloading string[] parameter.

if I change any changes to Program class main method it's not updating through my application .exe why?

copied code Before changing Program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

copied code below after adding arguments to mainb method i am checking for value and calling a method from other class

```
static class Program
{
    private static string x= string.Empty;
    private static string y= string.Empty;
    private static string z= string.Empty;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Count() > 0)
            {
                if (args.Count() != 3)
                {
                    RootDirectory = args[0];
                    SourceFile = args[1];
                    DestinationFile = args[2];
                    Form1.GetCommandLineArgs(x, y, z);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.AppUtilties.LogError(ex, "OnFailure, " + ex.Message);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be lots of things, from as simple as "did you compile it after making that change?" (the answer to which isn't stated in the question). Put a breakpoint in Main and run the program in Debug mode, and step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly answering the question, you might have better luck using

[Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx)

I usually use this for winforms, as you can access the args from anywhere in your code.